How to make a field in gorm that is readable but not written
DDL:
create table if not exists T
(
    A bigint,
    B bigint,
    C bigint generated always as (A + B) stored
);

Model:
type T struct {
    A int64
    B int64
    C int64
}

When I try to insert this structure, I get an error ERROR: cannot insert into column "C" (SQLSTATE 42601).
If I mark the C field as gorm:"-", then I don't get the value of this field when reading. Is there a way not to create two structures (one for writing, the second for reading), but to do with one?

You can use field level permissions:
`gorm:"<-:false"`  // allow read, disable write permission

